# Call route using inline JavaScript

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to call a route on enter key pressed using inline JavaScript.

Tried by defining variable inside view but when I pressed enter key nothing happens.

View:

```
<body>
<div class="form-group">
        <label for="search">Search Here :</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode == 13) check.click();" />
</div>

<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" type="text/js"></script>
<script>
        var check = "{{ route('users.search') }}";
</script>
</body>
```

Route:

```
Route::post('search', 'UserController@search')->name('users.search');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the input in a `form` markup and then when the user presses enter it will submit the form to the route you provide as the `action` attribute.

```html
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('users.search') }}">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="search">Search Here :</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="search" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I know this method but my form action is already set to <form method="POST" action="{{ route('users.store') }}"> hence I need help of JavaScript to achieve search functionality within same form.

Comment: You won't be able to make a post request without a form. You will need to use AJAX if you would like to do it with javascript and that would mean displaying the results which are returned by the ajax route by manipulating the DOM. The easiest way would be to take the search part outside of your other form and use this method.

Comment: Thanks, but is there no Laravel way? basically I want is when user enters id in "Search Here" field it should fetch all details of respective user and URL will look like this "http://localhost/users / {id} / edit" where {id} will be my input of "Search Here" field.